# Navigation of Tabnavigator in Stacknavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am working on a react native Project, where I am using both Stack navigator and Tab navigator.
The main flow of the application should be in stack navigation.I have added a button on one of the screens which is in tab navigation but the navigation is not happening!
How can I get that kindly help me out 
Sample code :

```
  const Nav=createStackNavigator({
    Splash: Splash,
    Login: Login,
    Tab:tab
  })

  const Tab=createBottomNavigator({
    Home:Home,
    Profile:Profile // i added button in this screen want to navigate to Login
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve the navigation issue by creating another stack for the screens which I want in tab navigation just as below and able to achieve the navigation.

```
//New Stack
 const Stack=createStackNavigator({
  Profile:Profile,
  Login:Login
    })
 //Old Stacks         
   const Tab=createBottomTabNavigator({
     Home:Home,
       Profile:Profile
   })
    const Nav=createStackNavigator({
      Splash:Splash,
      Login:Login,
      Tab:Tab
})
```